# Allegro 5: Tile Maps -> Scroll lag

Tags: dictionary, tiles, lag, frame-rate, allegro

I am currently working on a little Game im making

Now I've made a map via Tiled map Editor and put it on the screen via a al_draw_bitmap_region loop.
The map is shown on the screen, yet when i try to scroll the view, it takes ages until it goes forward.
This is probably caused by the "large" map (100x100)
-> in Allegro 4 i used this method once, too and it worked fine for me (i used to blit everything in the doubleBuffer and blit it on the screen)

Yet I seem to not find a solution for my problem in allegro 5 so far
I'm sorry if a board like this has already been open, I didnt found a solution for my problem so far.

I'd be really thankfull for help!

Code:

main.cpp:

```
#include<allegro5\allegro.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_image.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include "global.h"
#include "map.h"

using namespace std;



int main()
{

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_init_image_addon();
    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();
    al_init();

    ALLEGRO_FONT *font18 = al_load_font("arial.ttf", 18, 0);

    if (!al_init())
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL,NULL,NULL, "Could not initialize Allegro 5", NULL, NULL);
    }


    bool keys[] = {false, false, false, false};
    enum KEYS{UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT};

    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = NULL;

    bool done=false;
    bool reDraw=true;
    int xOff =0;
    int yOff =0;
    int count = 0;
    int FPS = 5;
    int x=10, y=10;
    int moveSpeed = 5;


    display = al_create_display(ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight);

    if(!display)
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL,NULL,NULL, "Could not create Allegro Window", NULL,NULL);


    al_set_window_title(display,"Outfall-RPG");

    al_install_keyboard();
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;

    event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / FPS);             // 1.0 = Sekunden; / FPS = Frames per Second

    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));

    al_start_timer(timer);



    while(!done)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);

        map map;
        map.Init();
        map.LoadMap("map1.txt");


        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                    done=true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT:
                    keys[LEFT] = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
                    keys[RIGHT] = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                    keys[UP] = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                    keys[DOWN] = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                    done=true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT:
                    keys[LEFT] = false;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
                    keys[RIGHT] = false;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                    keys[UP] = false;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                    keys[DOWN] = false;
                    break;
                }
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        {
            xOff -= keys[RIGHT] * 3;
            xOff += keys[LEFT] * 3;
            yOff -= keys[DOWN] * 3;
            yOff += keys[UP] * 3;

            reDraw=true;
        }
        if(reDraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue))
        {
            map.Draw(xOff, yOff);
            //al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(display));
            al_flip_display();
            al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));



            reDraw=false;

        }
    }

    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    return 0;
}
```

map.h

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include "global.h"
#include<allegro5\allegro.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>

using namespace std;

class map
{
    public:
        map();
        ~map();

        void Init();
        void Update();
        ALLEGRO_BITMAP  *buffer;

        void LoadMap(const char *filename);
        void Draw(int &xOff, int &yOff);

    private:
        int loadCounterX, loadCounterY;
        int mapSizeX, mapSizeY;
        int MapFile[200][200];
        int BlockSize;

        ALLEGRO_BITMAP  *bgSheet;



        int mapColumns;
        int mapSize;
        int y;
        int sheetSize;

};
```

map.cpp:

```
#include "map.h"

map::map()
{
    mapSizeX = 101;
    mapSizeY = 101;
    y=0;
    sheetSize = 13;
}

map::~map()
{
}

void map::Init()
{
    loadCounterX = loadCounterY = 0;
    map::LoadMap("maptest.txt");
    BlockSize = 32;
    int MapFile[100][100];
    mapColumns = 100;
    mapSize = 1000;

}

void map::Update()
{
}

void map::Draw(int &x, int &q)
{
    int xOff = x;
    int yOff = q;
    bgSheet = al_load_bitmap("bilder/testas1.png");
    buffer = al_create_bitmap(800,600);
    //al_set_target_bitmap(buffer);


        for (int i=0; i<mapSizeX; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<mapSizeY; j++)
            {
                y=0;

                while(MapFile[i][j] > sheetSize)
                {
                    MapFile[i][j] = MapFile[i][j] - sheetSize;  
                    y++;
                }

                // al_draw_bitmap_region(bgSheet, BlockSize*(MapFile[i][j]-1),BlockSize*y, BlockSize, BlockSize, xOff + BlockSize * (i%mapColumns), yOff + BlockSize * (j%mapColumns),0);
                //al_set_target_bitmap(buffer);
                al_draw_bitmap_region(bgSheet, BlockSize*(MapFile[i][j]-1),BlockSize*y, BlockSize, BlockSize, xOff + (BlockSize *i), yOff + (BlockSize * j),0);


                //al_set_target_backbuffer(display);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                // Generell gucken, wie ich schneller BITMAPS abbilden kann!
                //ALLEGRO_BITMAP *al_get_backbuffer(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display)
                //  al_set_target_bitmap(display);

                // Nur abgebildeter Bereich + Puffer blitten (20x20?)

            }
        }
}

void map::LoadMap(const char *filename)
{

    ifstream openfile(filename);
    if (openfile.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        getline(openfile, line);
        line.erase(remove(line.begin(),line.end(),' '), line.end());
        mapSizeX = 100;

        openfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        //openfile >> mapSizeX >> mapSizeY;

        while(!openfile.eof())
        {
            openfile >> MapFile[loadCounterX][loadCounterY];
            loadCounterX ++;

            if (loadCounterX >= mapSizeX)
            {
                loadCounterX = 0;
                loadCounterY++;
            }
        }

        mapSizeY = loadCounterY;
    }   //File is Opend

    else
    {
        //al_show_native_message_box(NULL,NULL,NULL, "Could not load Map", NULL,NULL);
    }
}
```

the tiles im using:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4DbZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines of `map::Draw` are suspicious:

```
bgSheet = al_load_bitmap("bilder/testas1.png");
buffer = al_create_bitmap(800,600);
```

`map::Draw` re-loads your bitmap every time you call it. Not only does this put needless load on your draw loop, but you are leaking the loaded bitmap every time.

Try loading `bgSheet` just once in `map::Init` and using that same bitmap for every draw loop.

You also allocate and subsequently leak a new `buffer` for every draw call. It appears that you aren't using the buffer, so I would remove that `al_create_bitmap` call entirely. If your intent was to double-buffer, that generally isn't needed in allegro5.

Also, it looks like `map::Init` is called in your game loop, which means you are repeatedly loading the map and probably spending a lot of time waiting on I/O. Call `map::Init` once before your game loop begins.

Comment: Another great speed-up will be to add `al_hold_bitmap_drawing(true)` at the beginning of the drawing function and the same call but with a `false` at the end of the function. This will send only one big draw call to the GPU that will draw the entire bitmap regions in a single go.

Answer (score 0):

it was indeed the map.init which was causing the lag because of the reloading of the map file!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Keep in mind this is not a forum, it is a Q&A site. So it is not a good practice to post a thank you message as a new answer to the question. You could have done that using a comment like this one at the answer. Although the acceptance of the answer was enough for @rcorte I think... Keep these tips in mind while you are here and welcome one more time :D

Comment: oh sorry, seems like i oversaw this method :D
i was just so happy when it finally worked out (I've been searching that for hours) I didnt took the time to see if there is an "add a comment" button :D

Anyways I'll keep that in mind, thanks for the reminder and the welcome ;)